# trouble wrapping my head around how to get values out of an html.for textbox in a cshtml page

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am having trouble retrieving the contents of a textbox which is created by `html.textboxfor`
 **cshtml is like this**

```
<div class="lx-row">
<div class="lx-width-300 lx-margin-top">
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.NumberOfProperties, new { @class = "form-control"
id = "divnumofprop",  type="number", val="2"})
```

**jQuery:**

```
var n1 = function ($) {
            $('input=#divnumofprop').innerText;
            alert(n1);
        };
```

I have tried this many different ways but always get that the value is undefined, not sure what I am doing wrong. scope is a concern here as well since the values are in a jQuery slider and slides get saved to db and swapped out with new content on clicking to move to next slide.

Answer (score 0):

To get the textbox value, you can use the [jQuery val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) function.

**For example,**

`$('input:textbox').val()` – Get textbox value.

`$('input:textbox').val("new text message")` – Set the textbox value.

In your case do as shown below :

Use `$("input[id='divnumofprop']").val();` instead of `$('input=#divnumofprop').innerText;`

**jQuery:**

```
var n1 = function () {
    var inputValue= $("input[id='divnumofprop']").val();
    alert(inputValue);
};
```

Comment: @webdev8183 Please confirm this solution is helpful to solve your problem statement. :-)

Answer (score 0):

[.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) function have to used here to fetch value of an input box.
It should be like:

```
$('#divnumofprop').val();
```

Also your code should

```
function () {
   var n1 = $('#divnumofprop').val();
   alert(n1);
};
```